# After expo eject, iOS app get in stuck at splash screen

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo, splash-screen

I started a react-native app using expo, but due to some native functionality I had to eject my app from expo. Still I have the `app.json` file having a `splash` field in which I have defined some parameter. The point is that after ejecting my app, if I run `react-native run-android` it works fine, the app shows me a splash screen and then goes on without any problem. If I do the same on iOS, meaning that I run my app on my iPhone through xcode, the app starts but gets in stuck on the splash screen and it doesn't go on. The only log I can get on the metro terminal is:

```
No native splash screen registered for given view controller. Call 'SplashScreen.show' for given view controller first.
```

But I have no idea what that means, I don't even know whether it is related to my problem or not. Moreover, within the iOS folder, the `.storyboard` file only shows the splash screen and nothing else. Is that normal?

Please help me, I can't find any useful information online.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Does Expo splash screen still work at all after ejecting?

Comment: Into my `App.js` file I imported `import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';` and then I added this code to the `useEffect` method: `async function dismissSplash() { await SplashScreen.hideAsync(); } dismissSplash()`. Not sure if it's the solution but it seems to work.